# UniswapV2 addLiquidityETH revert ds-math-sub-underflow

Tags: uniswapv2, revert, liquidity, anvil

I tried this code for many contracts, and sending ETH and approving were done well, but on the addliquidityETH section, I get an error: reverted with 'ds-math-sub-underflow'. I can't understand why.

```
const rpcUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8555"; // anvil --fork-url http://127.0.0.1:8545 --port 8555
const privateKey = ""; // Replace with your actual private key
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl);

const routerAddress = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'; // Replace with the actual router contract address.
const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60000; // Set the deadline to be 10 minutes from the current time
const abi =[]; //i use ERC-20 standard token ABI
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

async function impersonateAccount_addLiq(tokenAddress, contractOwner, amountETH) {
    try {
      // Impersonate the account
      await provider.send("anvil_impersonateAccount", [contractOwner]);
  
      // Create a signer for the impersonated account
      const signer = provider.getSigner(contractOwner);
      const router = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, ['function addLiquidityETH(address,uint256,uint256,uint256,address,uint256)'], signer);
      const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, abi, signer);
  
      const [tokenDecimals, ownerTokenBalance, ownerBalanceWei] = await Promise.all([
        tokenContract.decimals(),
        tokenContract.balanceOf(contractOwner),
        provider.getBalance(contractOwner)
      ]);
  
    //   const ownerTokenBalanceWithDecimals = ethers.utils.parseUnits(ownerTokenBalance.toString(), tokenDecimals);
      const ownerTokenBalanceWithDecimals = ownerTokenBalance; // No need to add decimals here

    //   const minAmountTokenWithDecimals = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", tokenDecimals);
      const minAmountTokenWithDecimals = ownerTokenBalance;
      const amountToLiquidity = ethers.utils.parseEther(amountETH);
  
      const sendEthTx = {
        to: contractOwner,
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("2"),
      };
      const sendResult = await wallet.sendTransaction(sendEthTx);
  
      const approveTx = await tokenContract.approve(routerAddress, ethers.constants.MaxUint256); // Approve the maximum amount
      await approveTx.wait();
  
      const allowance = await tokenContract.allowance(contractOwner, routerAddress);
      console.log("Allowance for Router:", allowance.toString());
  
      const gasLimit = ethers.BigNumber.from(3000000); // Increase the gas limit if needed

      console.log("Gas Limit: ", gasLimit.toString());
      console.log(ownerTokenBalanceWithDecimals.toString(),minAmountTokenWithDecimals.toString())
      console.log('ownerTokenBalance :',ownerTokenBalance.toString())
      console.log('tokenAddress :',tokenAddress)
      console.log('contractOwner :',contractOwner)
      console.log('amountToLiquidity :',amountToLiquidity.toString())

      const tx = await router.addLiquidityETH(
        tokenAddress,
        ownerTokenBalanceWithDecimals,
        minAmountTokenWithDecimals,
        amountToLiquidity,
        contractOwner,
        deadline,
        {
          gasLimit: gasLimit,
        }
      );
      console.log(`Added liquidity successfully`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred on impersonateAccount function:", error);
    }
  }
  
  impersonateAccount(tokenAddress, contractOwner, amountETH);
```

and here is one example of my run-with error.

```
Allowance for Router: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
ownerTokenBalance : 1000000000000000000
tokenAddress : 0x1995757da1Eb6ae05Fc6fe31f6ECdEdcb439Fb28
contractOwner : 0x0fd680D18Df75FD8d409c4c3349B250715fB1046
amountToLiquidity : 1000000000000000000
Error: reverted with 'ds-math-sub-underflow'
```

any help please.

Answer (score 0):

solved
issue was on router abi and missing value on addliquidityETH
after set correct abi for router and add value to tx was fixed

```
        {
          gasLimit: gasLimit,
          value:amountToLiquidity
        }
```